# Neo4j: How to use APOC apoc.algo.cover procedure?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Hi,

I try to use the "cover" function from APOC like this :

```
WITH ["f1,"f2",...] as list1 
MATCH (n:Frag) 
WHERE n.frag in list1 
WITH COLLECT(ID(n)) as nodeIds 
CALL apoc.algo.cover(nodeIds) 
YIELD rel  
RETURN rel
```

It works but it is very slow the first time. If I do it once again, it becomes muck quicker! What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your issue is not related to `apoc.algo.cover` usage, but to the `WHERE` part of your query. You can try a performance improvement adding an index in the `Frag.frag` property.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Frag(frag)
```

After creating the index run your query again. Note that the index is not immediately available, but will be created in the background.

Comment: Thank you for  your answer.

Comment: @PascalKREZEL Hi! You are welcome! Also, if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I have applied "CREATE INDEX ON :Frag(frag)" with a new request but it takes still too much time and it depends on the iteration of the same request => I open a new question to explain this problem.